# How do I fill a ListView (in Android) with XML or JSON data?

Tags: java, xml, android, listview, android-activity

I read a tutorial, and it uses SQLlite and "SimpleCursorAdapter" to fill the list with items.
This is the code the tutorial taught me.

```
private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

However...what if I want to fill it with XML data? Is it the same method? Can someone give me an example (in code)? thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example is using a `CursorAdapter` because a `Cursor` object is returned by the `NotesDbAdapter` (if i remember correctly ) `fetchAllNotes` method. I don't know if there is a way to pass in raw XML to create a list but you can use name/value pairs in a `HashMap` to create a list using the SimplelistAdapter.

You can parse your xml and or json and build a hash table with it and use that to populate a list. The following example doesn't use xml, in fact it's not dynamic at all, but it does demonstrate how to assemble a list at runtime. It's taken from the `onCreate` method of an activity that extends `ListActivity`. The all uppercase values are static constant strings defined at the top of the class, and are used as the keys.

```
// -- container for all of our list items
List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

// -- list item hash re-used
Map<String, String> group;

// -- create record
group = new HashMap<String, String>();

group.put( KEY_LABEL, getString( R.string.option_create ) );
group.put( KEY_HELP,  getString( R.string.option_create_help ) );
group.put( KEY_ACTION, ACTION_CREATE_RECORD );

groupData.add(group);

// -- geo locate
group = new HashMap<String, String>();

group.put( KEY_LABEL, getString(R.string.option_geo_locate ) );
group.put( KEY_HELP, getString(R.string.option_geo_locate_help ) )
group.put( KEY_ACTION, ACTION_GEO_LOCATE );

groupData.add( group );

// -- take photo
group = new HashMap<String, String>();

group.put( KEY_LABEL, getString( R.string.option_take_photo ) );
group.put( KEY_HELP, getString(R.string.option_take_photo_help ) );
group.put( KEY_ACTION, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO );

groupData.add( group );

// -- create an adapter, takes care of binding hash objects in our list to actual row views
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( this, groupData, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
                                                   new String[] { KEY_LABEL, KEY_HELP },
                                                   new int[]{ android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 } );
setListAdapter( adapter );
```