# simple_list_item_2 in Android

Tags: android, menu, listactivity

after creating some menus with `simple_list_item_1` (which worked very fine) I tried to replace this by `simple_list_item_2`, but my system throws around with exceptions...

Now I'm wondering how to create such a two-different-sized-line-entry for my list...is there any trap for beginners? Can someone please help me fixing my (small!?) problem?

My code looks like this:

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, fileNames);
setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

My `String[] fileNames` stores all strings to display in ascending order (does this matter for the functionality?!)

After unsuccessfully searching in some forums I now hope that someone of you can give me an useful suggestion.

nice greetings,
poeschlorn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`simple_list_item_2` is different, instead of just a TextView it contains a [TwoLineListItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html) containing *two* TextViews. ArrayAdapter is not going to work here, because the constructor you're using expects only a TextView; just look at the [constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). Instead you'll either have to create a custom adapter or use one that supports it like SimpleCursorAdapter or (I think) SimpleAdapter. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432951/how-to-display-a-two-column-listview-in-android/2437483#2437483) has a somewhat hacky solution that might work for you.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response :) I'm going to try this out and tell you if/how it works

Comment: hi again, I tried it out and it worked very well...the only thing I don't understand is, why is there a Map (or HashMap) needed?

Comment: I guess because the intended use is really to pull data from things that are already in key-value pairs, so it makes sense for that purpose. No reason there couldn't be, say, a 2dArrayAdapter or something, though. By the way, here's another good sample usage:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227154/how-do-i-fill-a-listview-in-android-with-xml-or-json-data/2227377#2227377

Comment: Hi, is it possible to give the simple_list_item_2 - objects an alternating background color?

Comment: SPECIFY IN THE LAYOUT.simple_list_item_2 IS AVAILABLE in the SDK. Copy it. and modify it. Refer your adapter to this XML

Comment: An example of a custom Adapter (which extends ArrayAdapter) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435645/proper-usage-of-twolinelistitem-android/12954944#12954944. You can replace the layout with a custom one.