# How to modify dummy content in android master/detail activity?

Tags: android

I would modify the items generated by eclipse in the master/detail schema. I can't find a way to do this. In particular I would take the items from an xml (res/values/arrays) resource file.

this is the java file:

```
package com.ga.termeapp.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class DummyContent {

    public static class DummyItem {

        public String id;
        public String content;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }

    public static List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();
    public static Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

    static {

        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Le terme"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Le cure termali"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", ""));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution :

Replace the static class by your own. In my case, `DummyItem` becomes [`ProfileItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435645/proper-usage-of-twolinelistitem-android/12954944#12954944) and has different attributes and `DummyContent` becomes `ProfileListContent`.

Then replace the static block `static { addItem ... }` by a static method. In the following case, I need to load items from a database :

```
public static void setContext(Context c) {
    if (db == null) db = new MyDbAdapter(c); // SQLiteOpenHelper + SQLiteDatabase manager
    if (db.isOpen() == false) {
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getProfiles(); // database query
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ProfileItem item = new ProfileItem(c.getString(0), c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2));
                addItem(item);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

I call the method `setContext` from my main activity at the beginning of the `onCreate` method, before any other operation.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ProfileListContent.setContext(this);
    ...
```

If you want to dynamically add an item :

```
public static void insertProfile(ProfileItem profile) {
    db.insertProfile(profile); // add item to the database
    addItem(profile); // the same addItem provided with the eclipse wizard
}
```

You can of course change the ListView Items' layout, I provided [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435645/proper-usage-of-twolinelistitem-android/12954944#12954944).

Comment: Since this gets generated every time you make a list or master/detail activity, a shortcut I use is: click on packages and class files and use `shift + F6` to refactor the names then I open the files and just replace `ctl + R` the DummyContent and DummyItems with whatever I want and begin from there.

Comment: Does the list of items remain static in your database backed implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but insted of taking all the values from an array I changed

```
addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Le terme"));
addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Le cure termali"));
addItem(new DummyItem("3", ""));
```

I edited those addItem and then if you want to add string to your items, you have to edit all this part of code.

```
    public String id;
    public String content;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me, not sure if it is the best practice.
Remove the static block and on the `ItemListActivity.java` on the `Oncreate` add this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (DummyContent.ITEMS.isEmpty())
    {
        DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("1", getResources().getString(R.string.menu1)));
        DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("2", getResources().getString(R.string.menu2)));
        DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("3", getResources().getString(R.string.menu3)));
    }
```

Hope this helps