# List<class> using strings.xml

Tags: android, string, list, arraylist, master-detail

Using Android's Studio I started with a Navigation Drawer activity. Then I added a Master Detail activity making a "real" class from the DummyContent class template. The application works when hard coding the items. My needs are to use multiple languages so I must use strings.xml for the language translations.

I extended ProductsAZ.java using Activity trying unsuccessfully to use "this" and "getString()". I can assign String header1 = getString(R.string.header1);. How do I use this design/class to call strings from strings.xml when adding a new Product item?

```
            addItem(new Product("1", "1_Title_here", "1_Header_here", "1_Body_here"));
            addItem(new Product("2", "2_Title_here", "2_Header_here", "2_Body_here"));
            addItem(new Product("3", "3_Title_here", "3_Header_here", "3_Body_here"));
```

Desire is:

```
        addItem(new Product("1", "@string/1_Title_here", "@string/1_Header_here", "@string/1_Body_here"));
```

ProductAZ.java

```
import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class ProductAZ extends Activity {

        // An array of items.
        // public static List<Product> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();
        public static List<Product> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();

        // A map of items, by ID.
        public static Map<String, Product> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>();

            // Add items.
            static {
                addItem(new Product("1", "1_Title_here", "1_Header_here", "1_Body_here"));
                addItem(new Product("2", "2_Title_here", "2_Header_here", "2_Body_here"));
                addItem(new Product("3", "3_Title_here", "3_Header_here", "3_Body_here"));
            }

        private static void addItem(Product product) {
            ITEMS.add(product);
            ITEM_MAP.put(product.id, product);
        }

        // An item representing a piece of content.
        public static class Product {
            public final String id;
            public final String title;
            public final String header;
            public final String details;

            public Product(String id, String title, String header, String details) {
                this.id = id;
                this.title = title;
                this.header = header;
                this.details = details;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return title;
            }
        }
}
```

ProductListActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * An activity representing a list of Products. This activity
 * has different presentations for handset and tablet-size devices. On
 * handsets, the activity presents a list of items, which when touched,
 * lead to a {@link ProductDetailActivity} representing
 * item details. On tablets, the activity presents the list of items and
 * item details side-by-side using two vertical panes.
 */
public class ProductListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        assert recyclerView != null;
        setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);

        if (findViewById(R.id.product_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
            // If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ProductAZ.ITEMS));
    }

    public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final List<ProductAZ.Product> mValues;

        public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<ProductAZ.Product> items) {
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.product_list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
            holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).title);

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                        ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.product_detail_container, fragment)
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final View mView;
            public final TextView mIdView;
            public final TextView mContentView;
            public ProductAZ.Product mItem;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProductDetailFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A fragment representing a single Product detail screen.
 * This fragment is either contained in a {@link ProductListActivity}
 * in two-pane mode (on tablets) or a {@link ProductDetailActivity}
 * on handsets.
 */
public class ProductDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    // The content this fragment is presenting.
    // private ProductAZ.Product mItem;
    private ProductAZ.Product mProduct;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ProductDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Load the content specified by the fragment
            // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
            // to load content from a content provider.
            mProduct = ProductAZ.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

            Activity activity = this.getActivity();
            CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            if (appBarLayout != null) {
                appBarLayout.setTitle(mProduct.title);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail, container, false);

        // Show the content as text in a TextView.
        if (mProduct != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_detail)).setText(mProduct.details);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

ProductDetailActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * An activity representing a single Product detail screen. This
 * activity is only used narrow width devices. On tablet-size devices,
 * item details are presented side-by-side with a list of items
 * in a {@link ProductListActivity}.
 */
public class ProductDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own detail action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
        // saved from previous configurations of this activity
        // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
        // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
        // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
        // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
        //
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
            // using a fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                    getIntent().getStringExtra(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
            ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.product_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, ProductListActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

product_detail.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/product_detail"
          style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:textIsSelectable="true"
          tools:context="com.bobh.znd6.ProductDetailFragment"/>
```

product_list.xml (small display)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/product_list"
                                        android:name="com.bobh.znd5.ProductListFragment"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                                        tools:context="com.bobh.znd6.ProductListActivity"
                                        tools:listitem="@layout/product_list_content"/>
```

product_list_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is solved... i needed to delete my switch statement in ProductAZ.java class and in the DetailListActivity.java i edited the onCreate method. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120569/how-to-modify-dummy-content-in-android-master-detail-activity/12175346)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found the solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120569/how-to-modify-dummy-content-in-android-master-detail-activity/12175346). I needed to delete my switch statement in ProductAZ.java. Then in DetailListActivity.java I edited the onCreate method. Using the prior post's outline fitting my class/method:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (DummyContent.ITEMS.isEmpty())
{
    DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("1", getResources().getString(R.string.menu1)));
    DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("2", getResources().getString(R.string.menu2)));
    DummyContent.addItem(new DummyItem("3", getResources().getString(R.string.menu3)));
}
```